# Remove every occurence of special characters in QString

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I remove every occurence of special characters ^ and $ in a QString?

I tried:

```
QString str = "^TEST$^TEST$";
str = str.remove(QRegularExpression("[^$]."));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to escape the `^`. To escape that, a `\` is needed, but that also needs to be escaped because of C strings. Also you want one ore more occurences to match with `+`. 
This regular expression should work: `[\\^$]+`, [see online](https://regex101.com/r/YF2AWP/1).

So it has to be:

```
QString str = "^TEST$^TEST$";
str = str.remove(QRegularExpression("[\\^$]+"));
```

Another possibility as said in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695198/remove-every-occurence-of-special-characters-in-qstring/44695333#comment76380685_44695333) by [Joe P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960709/joe-p) is:

```
QString str = "^TEST$^TEST$";
str = str.remove(QRegularExpression("[$^]+"));
```

because the `^` has just a special meaning at the beginning, where you have to escape it to get it literally, [see online](https://regex101.com/r/5PDe8R/1).

Comment: The weird thing is that my output is $$. Any ideas?!

Comment: You have to escape also the \ for C++; so it should look like str = str.remove(QRegularExpression("[\\^$]+"));

Comment: Or you could just reorder the characters in `[]` since `^` is only a special character at the beginning: `str = str.remove(QRegularExpression("[$^]+"));`

Comment: @JoeP: Very nice, didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using a regular expression where you can remove every non-alphanumeric character:

```
QString str = "$om<Mof*%njas"
str = str.remove(QRegExp("[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s]"));
```